# Difference in $_FILES structure when submitting and using XmlHttpRequest

Tags: php, javascript

I'm building a file uploader using the javascript FileAPI and XmlHttpRequest with a fallback to uploading via a hidden iframe. Both uploads are processed with PHP.

I however found an annoying difference in the way the $_FILES array is structured.

When using the iframe fallback, the array will look like this:

```
$_FILES = array(
    'files' => array(
        'name' => array(
            0 => 'name.jpg'
        ),
        'type' => array(
            0 => 'image/jpeg'
        )
        ...
    )
)
```

(I'm using multiple inputs called files[])

When I upload using an XmlHttpRequest, the array looks like this:

```
$_FILES = array(
    'filename' => array(
        'name' => 'name.jpg',
        'type' => 'image/jpeg'
        ...
    ),
    ...
)
```

Is there any way to make this behave the same way? Below you find how I build my xhr request:

```
var data = new FormData(), xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

data.append(file.name, file);

xhr.open('POST', 'process.php', true);

xhr.onload = function(e) {
    ...
};
xhr.send(data);
```

At the moment I parse the two different arrays like this, which seems to work.

```
 if(isset($_FILES['files']['name']))
 { // old skool $_FILES array
    foreach($_FILES['files'] as $key => $values)
    {
        foreach($values as $index => $value)
        {
            $files[$index][$key] = $value;
        }
    }
 } 
 else
 { // XMLHttpRequest $_FILES
    $files = $_FILES;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's the utterly moronic way PHP handles array-based file-field naming. If you have

```
<input type="file" name="whatever[]" />
                                 ^^---
```

you'll get the stupid sub-array based version you're seeing. There is no way around this - it's built into the core of PHP.

Comment: I see. I'v edited my OP with how I process it in PHP, seems fair?

Comment: so you're basically just transforming the normal "friendly" array version to the sub-array stuff? That'll work. Makes me shudder, though. it's one of my main peeves about PHP. It should've build the array as `$_FILES['file'][0 ... x][name/error/type/size]` instead, and made single-file uploads follow the same convention, with the single 0 index. Yet another example of poor planning/design in PHP.

Comment: Alas, it's also one of the most widely used languages, and writing it earns me money :p